# Intelligent Mail Barcode Encoding in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

This is a long shot, since from searching StackOverflow and the wider internet I'm fairly certain there's no way to do this in Powershell yet. But maybe one of you has some experience with this. Unfortunately, this question will probably look like gibberish to anyone who hasn't tried this themselves yet.

I'm trying to write a script in Powershell that can take an Intelligent Mail Barcode (0026110207649328762255101133230) and encode it into the proper barcode string (TADATFDAADFFFTATDAAFAATDTTDTDDADFAAFTADDTTTAFFAATTATFTADAFFADDFAD).

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a fair amount of code, including some translation tables.  We have an inexpensive app that will take  takE the
 postal info and create the letter string, and can be driven from a shell command. If that will help you, let me know.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm looking for, as long as it generates the TADF string. I've found tools that will generate the barcode image, but not give me the letter string.